# How to free memory in 2-D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a long code. But the logic is as follows:
I have a 2-D array in Java. So, I have values inside locations: `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2]` and values in:`[1][0], [1][1], [1][2]`. At this point, I made some comparisons, and I am done from the first row. I want to free the memory of: `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2]` and move to the next locations `[2][0], [2][1], [2][2]`.

How can I do something like this. I can not overwrite `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2]`,my code already programmed to move to the next row which is `[2][0], [2][1], [2][2]` but I faced memory constraints and I want to free memory from the first row `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2]` as I do not need it any more. I just need the current row and the previous to make a comparison. So, I want to delete the first row whenever I finish the comparison.

UPDATE: 
I tried to assign `NULL` to the unused array locations as the following:

```
for (int f = 0; f <= capacity; f++)
                      {  
                         table[f][i-2] = (Integer) null;  
                      }
```

My array is of type int and I only need the last two columns. The first one is not needed once I move one more position forward. When I applied the above code to assign `NULL`, I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Simply by writing some code and sharing the problem with others!

Comment: It is impossible to free the memory like what we do in the c. Assign the value to null helps the gc to kown the value is ready to free. *System.gc()* tells the gc to do some clean, but when the gc get to work is unkown.

Comment: It is too long and inconvenience to paste it as the logic behind it is also quite complicated and will make things unclear. It is better to just focus in this small issue.

Comment: you need to use references IF and IF the data-type of the array is Object-based

Comment: @user 2511414 can you clarify, I do not get the point.

Comment: @user2192774 If you are getting NullPointerException after setting the references to `null` then that means that you are using the references after you have nulled them.

If you are using the references after the loop, you cannot free their memory if you have used them in the loop.

On which particular line does the NullPointerException occur?

Comment: @user2192774 How do you initialize an array?

Answer (score 6):

set `null` to each reference in row

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{  
   arr[0][i] = null;  
}
```

`arr` should be array of references, not primal types

**EDIT**
for primal types (e.g. `int`) you can use wrapper-class (e.g. `java.lang.Integer` instead of `int` : `Integer[][]` instead of `int[][]`)

**EDIT2**
Equivalent for previous loop is:

```
arr[0] = new Integer[arr.length];
```

array `new Integer[arr.length]` contains `null` values

Comment: The GC might not necessarily free the memory if the object at the array index is still referenced somewhere else!

Comment: this is impossible if the array is a primitive guy

Comment: @Ilya Your answer works fine. But, I got stuck again as I have very very large array. Deleting it using loop is taking unfeasible amount of time. Is there any way that I can free a whole column in 2-D array in one shot without doing a loop ?

Comment: @user2192774 can you load array row by row instead of whole array?

Comment: @user2192774 for removing or initializing the array you need to initialize each Item, if even you array is really really big, you can do the initialization process in seconds with your GPU, or even a multi-thread approach

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have 2D arrays. They are mimicked by arrays whose elements are arrays.

You can set the first array of the array of arrays to null; this allows the GC to collect it and everything it contains.

```
arr[0]=null;
```

Note that this will work for arrays of both of arrays of primitive types and of objects. You don't need a loop.

An alternative to using `null` is using an empty array:

```
// Assuming arr is int[][]
private static final int[] EMPTY_ROW = {};
...
arr[0] = EMPTY_ROW;
```

Using an empty array you may be able to avoid adding null-checks and use simpler code in general, while obtaining the same effects as with `null`: the reference to the first row is removed, so it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

If you are interested in design patterns, this can be considered an application of the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: how do you set a primitive to null really?!

Comment: I think this is not `null safe`. `arr[0][?]` will throws `NPE`

Comment: @user2511414 He is saying that the array should be set to null. And you can set an `int[]` to null, because the array is an object even if the contents are primitives.

Comment: @Joni. Please check my update. It is 2-D array. How will `arr[0]=null;` would work? and it did not work with me. Java returned error because of the `null`.

Comment: @Alderath Opps, I'm really sorry buddy, I thought it's just in 1-D approach, thanks for the reply, sorry again

Comment: @Ilya That is kind of the point. The OP said that he wants to free the first row when he is done with it and doesn't need it any more. Based on what he's saying, it is guarantedd that `arr[0][?]` will never be accessed any more.

Comment: Edited to make the wording easier to understand, I hope.

Comment: If you got a null pointer exception that means you tried to use the first row even though you said you were done using it. You have a bug in your code.

Comment: @Joni I just display the array content to make sure it is null. When I use what you said: `arr[0]=null;` I get the error if I tried to printout the content. But if I used the loop method (mentioned in @Ilya answer, I see the null but his loop method taking unfeasible amount of time to free the array content. I am using Integer type and two dimension array as: `array[row][col]`. If your are sure that arr[0] will delete a 2-D array content, please, calridfy more to me as it does not work.

Comment: The printout method should have special treatment for `null` because it has no length nor elements to print. Or you can use the "null object pattern", see update. But remember that in Java you can't directly "delete" objects or arrays, you can only remove all references to them and have the garbage collector delete them for you.

Comment: @Joni O.0, the EMPTY_ROW is just time-wasting operation, you have just another n-length array to the memory, we need to remove the array from the memory, NO add another one

Comment: @user2511414, by assigning an empty array to `arr[0]` you rid yourself of an n-length array, possibly megabytes in size, at the expense of using 16 additional bytes that can be shared by all parts of the program. I don't see that unreasonable at all.

Comment: @Joni I see you buddy, but here we have n-length array waiting for gc, and another n-length that replaced with original one, the issue is that how to just remove the array from the memory, and also there is no warranty that user determine the array has empty or  original data

Comment: Where do you get a second n-length array? An empty array is empty, it has length 0.

Comment: @Joni I'm just really sorry, I didn't got the empty declaration, sorry, really sorry :(